# Clearing all orders from Magento Store

Tags: magento-1.7, database, orders, sales-order

I have filled my database with a bunch of test data.  Before going live I want to clear all the test orders in the database. I view my database using cPanel usually.

What is the best way to clear ALL orders, yet keep all my customers and their data?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by multiple ways. 
**Please test in development or take backup before use any way to do this.**

Short and simple use module and remove orders. below is some module. I am not associate with any module. Please try on development or take backup.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/orders-eraser.html
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-orders-6.html

Another way is Run sql query to remove order data. below is sql to remove all orders from database

```
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_address`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_payment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_status_history`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_payment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_track`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_aggregated_created`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE `sendfriend_log`; 
TRUNCATE `tag`; 
TRUNCATE `tag_relation`; 
TRUNCATE `tag_summary`; 
TRUNCATE `wishlist`; 
TRUNCATE `log_quote`; 
TRUNCATE `report_event`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_status_history` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_track` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_payment_transaction` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_tax` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_tax_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sendfriend_log` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `tag` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `tag_relation` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `tag_summary` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `wishlist` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `log_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `report_event` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```